# Scala accept both parameterless function and zero-parameter function as overloads

Tags: scala, types, overriding, implicit, type-deduction

I'd like to define a method that can be used as follows:

```scala
foo.withData {(a, b) =>
  // ...
}

foo.withData {() =>
  // ...
}

foo.withData {
  // ...
}
```

I know I can sort-of support all three (for sure the bottom two) by accepting a lazily evaluated parameter (parameterless function) and running the evaluated result if it is a function:

```scala
class Foo {
  def withData[T](codeBlock: => T): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock match {
      case x: ((String, String) => Unit) => x("string-a", "string-b")
      case x: (() => Unit) => x()
      case _: Unit => {}
    }
    // Teardown
  }
}
```

However, the first call doesn't work because the function types can't be inferred (it would have to be `foo.withData {(a: String, b: String) => ...}`).

I also know I can support the first two with simple function overloading:

```scala
class Foo {
  def withData(codeBlock: (String, String) => Unit): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock("string-a", "string-b")
    // Teardown
  }
  def withData(codeBlock: () => Unit): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock()
    // Teardown
  }
}
```

Is there any way to support all three (with the implicit function argument deduction) at once or is it impossible?

**Background on my specific problem:** I'm trying to create an easy to use utility that handles resource creation and destruction similar to Python's `with` statement:

```scala
resourceManager.withResources(File("a.txt"), PngImage("b.png")) {(aFile, bImage) =>
  // ...
}
val aFile = File("a.txt")
val bImage = PngImage("b.png")
resourceManager.withResources(aFile, bImage) { () => // For when not instantiating inline
  // ...
}
resourceManager.withResources(aFile, bImage) { // It's nice not to need () => here
  // ...
}
```

Currently, this mostly works by having `withResources` return a custom object whose apply method acts like the `withData` method described above.

Comment: You know, if the idea is to handle resources, you shouldn't allow them to define them outside of your function. Because you shouldn't close a resource that still has a reference outside your scope. BTW, do you know that the stdlib already have that since `2.13`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What part of 2.13 are you referring to? And also, in my specific case, defining resources outside the creation is a necessary tradeoff to allow for interdependent references.

Comment: How about using a typeclass?

Comment: @MatthewD.Scholefield Why is this a big deal to write explicitly `foo.withData {(a: String, b: String) => ...}`?

Comment: @user it doesn't help https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ipMJi8hXSOeVGFMsbYAFDA

Comment: @DmytroMitin You're right, I didn't realize you can't infer parameter types just like that

Comment: @MatthewD.Scholefield I am referring to [**Using**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html). You may also want to give a look to [**Resource**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Resource.html) from `cats-effect` _(or [**Managed**](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_managed) from `ZIO`)_. - BTW, the way in which you will handle interdependent resources with those is by nesting them.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `callback: () => Unit` and `callback: => Unit`?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use overloading with `DummyImplicit`

```
class Foo {
  def withData(codeBlock: (String, String) => Unit): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock("string-a", "string-b")
    // Teardown
  }
  def withData(codeBlock: () => Unit): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock()
    // Teardown
  }
  def withData(codeBlock: => Unit)(implicit dummyImplicit: DummyImplicit): Unit = {
    // Setup
    codeBlock
    // Teardown
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create 2 functions to be able to pass in as many resources as you like to the `withResources` method, along with a function that operates on those resources, in a type-safe way.

```
Foo.withResources {
  println("Hello")
}

//Note that you could remove the parantheses 
Foo.withResources(1, "string-a", List()) {
  case (a, b, c) =>
    println(a + 2)
    println(b.length)
    println(c.size)
}
```

The output of that is this:

```
Setup 1
Hello
Teardown 1

Setup 2
3
8
0
Teardown 2
```

The method needed to make it work:

```
object Foo {
  def withResources(callback: => Unit): Unit = {
    println("Setup 1")
    callback
    println("Teardown 1")
  }

  def withResources[T <: Product](t: T)(callback: T => Unit): Unit = {
    println("Setup 2")
    callback(t)
    println("Teardown 2")
  }
}
```

I don't think there's any need to have another method using a callback of type `() => Unit`. You can always convert a `callback: => Unit` with a function literal like `() => callback` if you need to, but judging from your example both variants did the same thing, and it was only a matter of syntax. If you're not passing a function literal to `withResources`, you could always do `withResources(args)(myfunction())` to go from a `Function0` to `=> Unit`

The first `withResources` function is exactly what you'd expect - it takes a call-by-name parameter that you can input in curly braces for convenience, does the setup stuff, calls `callback`, and then runs the teardown process.

The second one takes a tuple and a function that can operate on that tuple. The `callback` function, however, should be a pattern-matching anonymous function (or declare one parameter of some tuple type). Auto-tupling makes it so you don't have to put parentheses around your tuple. This way, you can use as many resources as you want (as long as they're less than 22:)).

In Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d0BdLkInSP2lHgqpaZozGw